# Struggling to apply CSS styles to Elm application

Tags: css, functional-programming, frontend, elm

I’ve been having issues figuring out the best approach to style Elm 19 applications. Here is what I’ve been trying but to no avail:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Styled.Attributes exposing (css)
import List exposing (..)
import Css exposing (..)

type alias Model = List Status
type alias Status = { status : String }


main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


-- Note: I removed the init, update, and subscriptions functions from this code snippet as it does not seem like they were relevant to my question.


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    main_ 
        [ css
        [ color (hex "ffffff")
        , backgroundColor (hex "000000")
        , Css.height (vh 100) ]
        ]
        [ h1
            [ css [ margin (px 0) ] ]
            [ text "The title of my app" ]
        , input [ value ""] []
        ]
```

The compiler points out that the problem I’m having in `main_` is the following:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
This argument is a list of type:

    List #(Html.Styled.Attribute msg)#

But `main_` needs the 1st argument to be:

    List #(Attribute msg)#
```

Here is the `elm.json` file:

```
{
    "type": "application",
    "source-directories": [
        "src"
    ],
    "elm-version": "0.19.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm/browser": "1.0.2",
            "elm/core": "1.0.5",
            "elm/html": "1.0.0",
            "elm/time": "1.0.0",
            "ianmackenzie/elm-units": "2.9.0",
            "justinmimbs/date": "4.0.1",
            "rtfeldman/elm-css": "18.0.0"
        },
        "indirect": {
            "elm/json": "1.1.3",
            "elm/parser": "1.1.0",
            "elm/url": "1.0.0",
            "elm/virtual-dom": "1.0.3",
            "robinheghan/murmur3": "1.0.0",
            "rtfeldman/elm-hex": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    "test-dependencies": {
        "direct": {},
        "indirect": {}
    }
}
```

I suspect that I might be using an old version of `elm-css` or something along these lines but I'm having a hard time understanding what's not working here for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use `elm-css` you need to have a conversion from `Html.Styled.Html` to `Html.Html` using `Html.Styled.toUnstyled`. This means you need to have `import Html.Styled exposing (..)` instead of `import Html exposing (..)`

This means that `main_` will be `Html.Syled.main_` instead of `Html.main_` (as it is right now).

You could then add at the end of your `view` code `|> Html.Styled.toUnstyled` and everything should work out fine.

Comment: Thank you. Exposing `Html` instead of `Html.Styled` was indeed the problem. I was able to fix the issue and put `toUnstyled` to use. Thanks!